# errors of running an interface with java swing

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

when I run my Interface created with  java swing netbeans the Jbuttons move from their original location and many errors appear. I didn't find what those errors mean. 
while running the interface, it always stops working and it stuck.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsTabbedPaneUI.paintContentBorder(WindowsTabbedPaneUI.java:145)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.paint(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:791)
    at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:779)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1055)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:888)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1064)
    at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:731)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:888)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1064)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5232)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:295)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1249)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5180)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4991)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:808)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:796)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:796)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:769)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:718)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1100(RepaintManager.java:62)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1677)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556)

Comment: *"I didn't find what those errors mean"* What research did you do? Note that we see questions asking about `NullPointerException` pretty much every day on SO. In your programming, it is likely you'll see many more exceptions and errors. Don't come running to us about them, until you've done extensive research and can ask a more specific question. SO is a Q&A site, not a help desk. *"Jbuttons move from their original location"* It's possible that is completely unrelated to the NPE. If so, it should not be lumped into the same question. For better help on that, post a [MCVE].